# Is there an Elegant way to use Razor Blade to add TagToolbar()?

Tags: 2sxc

Am I missing something obvious? In a 2sxc CSharp View, how can I get the HtmlString output of `Edit.TagToolbar(item)` in to a Tag using RazorBlade?

```
 @Tag.Div(item.Title).Attr(Edit.TagToolbar(item))   // is there a way to do this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it will work. The docs kind of assume it does: https://razor-blade.net/api/ToSic.Razor.Markup.Tag-1.html#ToSic_Razor_Markup_Tag_1_Attr_System_Object_

...but you may need to ToString() it... try this

```
@Tag.Div(item.Title).Attr(Edit.TagToolbar(item).ToString())
```

If this was all that was missing, we'll probably see if we can enhance RazorBlade to make it unnecessary.

Comment: It worked only after I noticed the `@using` still said Connect.Razor.Blade. Once I changed it to ToSic.Razor.Blade and started using the modern version it started working.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I sent ahead and added the enhancement request on the GitHub project. Cheers!!